# How to build a trigger which has nested if

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have three tables:

1. Project - keeps all the detail of the project. ProNo is the primary key.
2. Staff - keeps all the data of the staff. StaffNo is the primary key.
3. ProjectStaff - shows who is doing the project and also a link entity between project and staff. It has the position of each staff in the project. ProNo and StaffNo are foreign keys.

A staff member can be assigned to more than one project at the same time, but a project can only have one leader.

Since I want to make sure, in the ProjectStaff table, each ProNo could only have one 'leader'.

Should I use nested If or Case to implement it in the trigger? And How should I implement it?

Since I am just a SQL beginner, I really need some suggestion on this, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you look at other _Oracle_ tagged questions in _Stack Overflow_? Usually the person posting the question provides database table structure details as well as sample data. Please forgive me if I missed the obvious, but I counldn't find any table structure details nor sample data in your post. Perhaps you could provide them? Table structure details should include column names, column data types and sizes, e.g. `project varchar2(30)`.

Comment: Thanks, project table has a primary key `ProNo varchar2(5)` and staff table has a primary key `StaffNo varchar2(5)`, ProjectResearcher has foreign keys from project and staff tables. thanks for your help

Comment: Need table structure. Also, no information about this 'leader' column(which table has and which doesn't). Please provide detailed problem case if you are asking 'And How should I implement it?' As per your problem case 'Since I want to make sure, in the ProjectStaff table, each ProNo could only have one 'leader'', I believe this can be solved by enforcing a constraint,please provide detail why you are planning to use trigger

Comment: `CREATE TABLE Project
(ProNo VARCHAR2(5) CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY, 
StartDate DATE NOT NULL;

CREATE TABLE Staff
(StaffNo VARCHAR2(5) CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE ProjectStaff
(ProNo VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ProNo) REFERENCES Project(ProNo),
StaffNo VARCHAR2(5) FOREIGN KEY (ReNo) REFERENCES Researcher(ReNo),
Role VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT CHECK(PTRole = 'Leader' OR PTRole = 'Member'));`
this's table structure, and I just want only one staff in the project to be a Leader.thanks:)

Comment: @thcuwl those CREATE TBLE statements are invalid. Also this should be part of your question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the table structures but this is a problem which can be easily solved with the correct projection for the intersection table `ProjectStaff`. I would solve this by putting the ROLE_TYPE column (i.e. whether the staff member is the leader or the led) on that table.

So that table would look like this:

```
create table projectstaff (
     projectno varchar2(5) not null
     , staffno varchar2(5) not null
     , roletype varchar2(10) constraint projectstaff_role_ck check (roletype in ('Leader', 'Minion'))
     , constraint projectstaff_pk primary key (projectno, staffno)
     , constraint projectstaff_project_fk foreign key (projectno) references project         
     , constraint projectstaff_staff_fk foreign key (staffno) references staff
);
```

Then we have build a unique **function-based** index, which allows us to enforce a rule that a project can only have one staff member with an assigned ROLETYPE of 'Leader'.

```
create unique index projectstaff_uidx on projectstaff
    (projectno, case when roletype = 'Leader' then roletype else staffno end)
;
```

Comment: Since you edited your answer, my original comment is no longer relevant, hence I deleted it. By the way, it was not a criticism of your answer - I was just trying to be funny.

Comment: @abra - it's okay, I know you were joking. Your comment just prompted me to polish my answer